# Mozilla firefox build fails with 'does not match the static pattern 'c:/C''

Tags: firefox, build, mozilla

I've followed the [simple firefox build instructions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Simple_Firefox_build#Get_the_source), but the following error occured:

```
Gabor@AMANDA /c/dev/mozilla-central
$ ./mach build
 0:00.36 C:/mozilla-build/msys/bin/sh.exe -c c:/mozilla-build/python/python.exe
c:/dev/mozilla-central/build/pymake/make.py -f client.mk -s
 0:03.79 Adding client.mk options from c:/dev/mozilla-central/.mozconfig:
 0:03.79     MOZ_OBJDIR=$(TOPSRCDIR)/obj-ff
 0:03.79     FOUND_MOZCONFIG := c:/dev/mozilla-central/.mozconfig
 0:04.83 c:\dev\mozilla-central\obj-ff\backend.RecursiveMakeBackend.pp:1:0:Targe
t 'backend.RecursiveMakeBackend' does not match the static pattern 'c:/C'
 0:04.83 c:\dev\mozilla-central\client.mk:398:0: command 'c:/mozilla-build/pytho
n/python.exe c:/dev/mozilla-central/build/pymake/pymake/../make.py -j4 -C c:/dev
/mozilla-central/obj-ff' failed, return code 2
 0:04.83 c:\dev\mozilla-central\client.mk:185:0: command 'c:/mozilla-build/pytho
n/python.exe c:/dev/mozilla-central/build/pymake/pymake/../make.py -f c:/dev/moz
illa-central/client.mk realbuild' failed, return code 2
 0:04.95 0 compiler warnings present.
2
```

Anyone knows what can be the problem?

Mozconfig only contains this:
    mk_add_options MOZ_OBJDIR=@TOPSRCDIR@/obj-ff

Comment: I did mach clobber as well

Comment: Do you meet all the prerequisites ? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Developer_Guide/Build_Instructions/Windows_Prerequisites